# Android and glOrthof

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am developing a simple tile world game for Android 2.3.  I am trying to set up an orthographic view in opengl but my 1x1 tiles show up oblong -- oriented to the direction of the screen -- if the screen is in vertical position then the square is stretched vertically, if horizontal then it is stretched horizontally.  Here is what I have in my onSurfaceChanged method:

```
gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glOrthof(0.0f, width, 0.0f, height, 1.0f, 100.0f);
```

In my onDrawFrame method I have:

```
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 
    0.0f, 0.0f, 6.0f, // eye translation 
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // eye center
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f  // eye world up
    ); 
// draw objects
```

From the object onDraw method:

```
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[0]);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mFloatVertexBuffer);
gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mTexBuffer);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glTranslatef(localTranslation.getX(), localTranslation.getY(), localTranslation.getZ());
gl.glScalef(localScale.getX(), localScale.getY(), localScale.getZ());
gl.glRotatef(mAngle, localRotation.getX(), localRotation.getY(), localRotation.getZ());
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
gl.glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
gl.glPopMatrix();
gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

I have used the same onSurfaceCreated, onDrawFrame, and onDraw methods with perspective mode and it worked without any distortion to the objects being drawn. I have tried a few different things pulled from the net (like replacing the right/bottom of the ortho call with width/height aspect ratio) but nothing seemed to correct the problem.

Here is what the screen looks like:

[image: The images should be perfect 1x1 squares in ortho mode.]

Any ideas?  What am I missing? All that I want to see are perfect 1x1 squares that I can throw textures on without distortion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glOrthof(0.0f, width, 0.0f, height, 1.0f, 100.0f);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW); 
gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

Comment: Didn't work.  In fact, nothing displayed after calling matrix mode modelview and loadidentity.  I have updated my post to show how my objects are being drawn and what the screen looks like in vertical mode.  I'm thinking this has something to do with the aspect ratio, and will explore in that direction, but I'm unsure how/where to apply it.

Comment: I solved the oblong-ness problem by using the screen aspect ratio in the ortho call as `gl.glOrthof(-ratio, ratio, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.01f, 100.0f)` but now the tiles appear to be too big.  They are of the same size as the image I posted, but they need to be much smaller so that if I have a 32x32 pixel texture on a 32x32 sized tile it takes up exactly 32x32 pixels on the screen.  How is this done?

Comment: Actually, SteveL's answer was correct.  It was a mistake on my part that I did not scale up my 1x1 squares to a viewable size. After I upped the scale on the squares to 48 they were visible and completely square!

Answer (score 0):

Ok this setting is what i use for both iOS and Android but when the screen ratio differs then positions of objects change.

```
glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);

glOrthof(-1.0,                  //LEFT 
         1.0,                   //RIGHT
         -1.0 * backingHeight / backingWidth,  //BOTTOM
         1.0 * backingHeight / backingWidth,   //TOP
         -2.0,                  //NEAR
         100.0);                //FAR
```

NOTE: That this works for normalised coordinates, which is what i use for all of my models.